# Django and PostgreSQL - how to store time range?

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to store a time range (without dates) like "HH:MM-HH:MM".
Can you give me a hint, how can I implement it most easily? Maybe there is a way to use DateRangeField for this aim or something else.
Thanks for your spend time!

Comment: You won't be able to use `DateRangeField` as it will only resolve to a date. Your choices would seem to be either: 1) Two time columns e.g time_start, time_end 2) An `ARRAY` of times.

Answer (score 0):

Time without date doesn't make much since if you ever need a range that span mid-night (days) You could always convert to text using to_char(<yourtimestamp>,'hh24.mi:ss') or extract the individual parts. Unfortunately Postgres does not provide an extract(time from <yourtimestamp>) function. The following function provides essentially that.

```
create or replace 
function extract_tod(date_time_in timestamp without time zone) 
  returns time 
  language sql 
as $$
   select to_char(date_time_in, 'hh24:mi:ss')::time;
$$;
```

See here for [timestatamp ranges](http://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and here for their associated [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html). As for how to store then just store with the date
as a standard TIMESTAMP (date + time).